# Mocking Oauth providers while testing

Tags: python, web-applications, oauth-2.0, flask

I have an app that I'm writing which authenticates against an Oauth 2.0 authorisation server. I'd like to test the parts that are accessible only after you've logged in but the Oauth server is an external dependency that complicates and make brittle my tests.

Any suggestions on how I should go about this? What the industry practices for something like this? My gut feel is to somehow mock out the server so that it allows access to the protected resources.

In case it matters, this is a Python webapp written using Flask.

I am using a custom oauth server which will run on my own domain and while it's possible to add some kind of sandboxing functionality as FoxMask has suggested, I'd much prefer being able to run the test without requiring an extra server running.

Comment: usually, the "external" Oauth (like for service Twitter, Evernote etc) provide a sanbox to make our tests. Dont you have found one for that purpose ?

Comment: But they'd still require you to authenticate against them? Just that they send you dummy credentials for the test?

Comment: yes of course they require that. yes they returned a dummy credentials or equivalent. Evernote, for example, provides special keys for test purpose only. And that does the trick to finish our dev with the API. Once you'll curl your dev to push in production, you'll get new api key for production.

Comment: My Oauth2 provider is a [custom server](https://github.com/hasgeek/lastuser) that runs on my own machine. I could add this functionality in there but I'd much prefer being able to run the tests without even needing an actual running Oauth server.

Comment: I see, you should have started by this details. I would have avoided to speak about useless things for you ;) So we are now return to the starting point. sorry.

Comment: Mea Culpa. I've fixed the question to point this out.

Comment: So you can check if your are in `DEBUG` then provides a fake response from a `mock class` that will always return True or something meaning the user is auth. (that was my last answer, the next one will suggest us to start a " chat " exchange.)

Answer (score 11):

From the consumer (i.e. your application) side, the OAuth2 process can be separated in two parts:

1. the redirect from your application to the OAuth2 provider's "authorize" URL
2. the exchange of the "code" returned by the OAuth2 provider for an access token

For #1 all you need to test is that when you invoke the route that starts the authentication process the response returned is a redirect to the OAuth2 provider. This is easily accomplished with Flask's [test client](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/testing/). The response should have a status code of 302 and a "Location" header set to the authorize URL for your OAuth2 provider. Note that you do not need to provider to be up, you are just testing that the response is a redirect, but you do not need to actually redirect.

Testing for #2 is a little bit more involved. Your Flask app has a special URL that is designated as the "redirect URL" for the OAuth2 provider to send you back the authorization code. You can just invoke this URL with the Flask test client passing a mock code and that has no issue.

The problem is that in the view function that handles your redirect URL you need to invoke the OAuth2 provider to exchange the auth code for an access token, and this is done synchronously. To prevent this transaction to happen you have to check `app.config['TESTING']` and in that case skip the actual request and replace it with a fake response that includes a mock access token.

From then on you will need to also fake any additional calls into the OAuth2 provider that send the access token to request data.

If you are using an OAuth2 client library in your Flask app it may be easier to create the mock provider without having to create testing exceptions in your application. In my case I'm using [rauth](https://github.com/litl/rauth), and for this I have created a subclass of the `OAuth2Service` class that overrides the proper methods and responds with mock data that I have captured from a real session. Then in my test setup I just create the mock service and the application is fooled into thinking it is talking to a real server.

I hope this helps.

Comment: So for subclassing the OAuth2Service, you have to sufficiently separate the creation of the session so you can dictate which version of OAuth2Service to instantiate for the tests?